# Cannot read property 'substring' of undefined issue in Qunit Test case

Tags: jquery, qunit, blanket.js

In my javascript file below mentioned code is present. But when I run Javascript test cases via Qunit.js and Blanket.js
I am getting this error in chrome: "Cannot read property 'substring' of undefined - {}"

```
if ($("label[for=ReservationInformation]").text().substring(0, 1) != "*") {
            $("label[for=ReservationInformation]").text("*" + $("label[for=ReservationInformation]").text());
        }
```

I have defined test case as:

```
test("validationChecker test", 1, function () {
    var div = $('<div>').appendTo("body");
    $('<input>', { id: "ReservationInformation" }).appendTo(div);
    $('<label>', { "for": "ReservationInformation" }).appendTo(div);
    var result = validationChecker(null);
    equal(undefined, result, "passed");
    $("div").remove();
});
```

Comment: `substr() ma men`

Comment: Is $("label[for=ReservationInformation]").text() returns anything in console?

Answer (score 0):

I think that, the problem is in your test case you don't set a text for your label, try changing the label creation by this :

```
$('<label>', { "for": "ReservationInformation", "text": "Hello" }).appendTo(div);
```